# How can I remove this seam down the middle after mirroring?

Tags: modeling, mirror

Yo,

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to make a humanoid figure. I followed [this tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Modeling_a_Human_Character_-_Modeling). I have completed one half of the character but when I mirror it there is a seam down the middle. Clipping is on, too, and all the answers I found are to do with turning it on. I'm stumped.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

M~

Answer (score 1):

I think the vertices that should be in the middle of your character, are slightly beyond the axis, like that :
[image]

In Edit mode, select all your vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>) and move them to the left* until they "stick" to the mirror axis (this is what Clipping does).

*left in my example, maybe right in yours